# EJB Session Bean / Client Hibernate Session interaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb

in a school project we are using an EJB Session Bean,
this EJB offers simple services such as add, delete, modify, findAll, findbyId. Such methods are implemented using hibernate 4.0 (add -> saveOrUpdate, modify -> saveOrUpdate...) and are available for the client

I have two classes :  Game (id, description, category) and Category (id, title). 
A category has also a set of games. 
The ids are generated using the identity generator. The databased used is mysql.

In the client 
A form is used by the application user to fill out informations about a game (description and category ) In the controller I use the method findById to get the category that the user chose, then I create a new game with this category and I save it (using SaveOrUpdate)

first problem that I notice : the id is generated correctly in the EJB and the game passed is modified but back in the client the game doesn't have an id (I guess passing objects between a client and a EJB is not by reference) Can anyone confirm it ?

second problem : when the game is save I tried to add this game to the set of the category and update this category (using also saveOrUpdate). I get the exception org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: 
a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
which I don't understand

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: can you post some code? I can't really help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, it sounds like the ID isn't being sent back to the client, or being stored with the controller . 
You could send it back to the client by adding it to the URL, ie, in the return from the client call  add "?id=" + newGameId

With this you can have the value populate back into the controller with setters and getters for an id field;

```
long id;
```